# Android square video record with post proccessing

Tags: android, camera, ffmpeg, crop, post-processing

I to allow users in my app to record video and then post process it. Basically all I need is to video to be square (low res, something about 400x400) and when recording is done then allow user to modify brightness/contrast.

I did some research on that and found ffmpeg library which can do that. But I'm not sure if I am ok with its licensing. When I use ffmpeg do I have to release my app sources as well? My app will be free to download and use but I am not comfortable with its releasing sources.

Also about that square recording - as I am supporting API 14, android doesn't let me adjust resolution directly. There are 2 ways I think of:

1. Record video file in 640x480, then resize/crop and after that allow user to do post processing. - totally need ffmpeg for that
2. Capture CameraPreviewFrames - crop them as they go and render them into mp4 video, and after video is rendered then allow user to post process it further -  need ffmpeg for that as well.

My question is then - may I use ffmpeg without any worries about licensing etc?
Or is there any other library which allows me to do above and is open to use?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer, and this is not legal advice. You should consult your lawyer for real legal advice.

FFmpeg is [LGPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html). You should read the license; it's somewhat more readable than most legalese.

The LGPL differs from the GPL in that you are not required to distribute your source code so long as you do not incorporate FFmpeg source code into your project. To achieve this, you must use FFmpeg as a so-called dynamic link library (e.g., .so, .dylib, .framework, .dll, etc). This is the default configuration.

If you modify the FFmpeg source, you must make it available.

You must also comply with the copyright license/patent license restrictions of all codecs you compile with FFmpeg. These are possible to distinguish by the FFmpeg configure options, e.g. `--enable-gpl`. If you use this configure option, for example, you are agreeing to distribute your source code as well as the FFmpeg source code, subject to the requirements of that codec's license(s). (In the case of x264, I believe there is [a commercial license](http://x264licensing.com/) as well as the GPL.)

Straight from the horse's mouth: http://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html

Especially check the checklist.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is some another library which I can use for my goal?

Answer (score 1):

For API 11+, you can use the stagefright framework to encode your video to mp4, you don't need ffmpeg for this.

OTOH, there are quite a few ports of ffmpeg to Android, some even [install a separate service](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android) whose sole purpose is to provide ffmpeg support for any app on the device. Using such approach you definitely do not violate any SW licenses.

Comment: THANKS. And does Stagefright have capabilities to resize/crop video and adjust its brightness and contrast please?

Comment: No, stagefright will not resize, crop, or adjust the video for you. It is relatively easy to crop the frames explicitly in your camera preview callback. Resize is trickier; color adjustment may require external libs.